# SQL - Matching on a set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Lets say I have a many to many relationship:

```
Profile  <-  Profile_Attribute  -> Attribute
-------      -----------------     ---------
ProfileID    Profile_AttributeID   AttributeID
Name         ProfileID             Name
             AttributeID
             Value
```

Looking at the data, a profile has 2 attributes, attribute A and attribute B.  I want to find any profile record that has all the attributes with matching values, without hard coding the attribute ID's/Names.  So basically I want to pass a table to a query that contains the attributes, and it will find any profile record that matches.  Profile records will only match if the exact attributes are the same, ie.  it can't have more attributes, less attributes on ones with different values.

This is the SQL I came up with.  Just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
--Declare the set of attributes/values that I want to find matching profiles for
DECLARE @tblCheck TABLE
(
    AttributeID INT,
    Value VARCHAR(255)
)

--We're looking for any profile record that has an attribute 2 of abc and 
--an attribute 1 of xyz, but nothing else
INSERT INTO @tblCheck (AttributeID, Value) VALUES (2, 'abc')
INSERT INTO @tblCheck (AttributeID, Value) VALUES (1, 'xyz')

--Find all profiles that have the same attributes and the same values
SELECT 
    p.ProfileID, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Profile] p
JOIN
    [Profile_attribute] pa ON pa.ProfileID = p.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN
    @tblCheck c ON pa.AttributeID = c.AttributeID AND
                   --Match on exact value or a wildcard
                   (pa.Value = c.Value OR pa.Value = '*')
GROUP BY
    p.ProfileID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tblCheck)
```

Comment: Sample and expected data could be better.

Comment: why are you using a left outer join instead of an inner join with your @tblCheck?

Comment: Yea, good call,  I'm not sure why I did that! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are simply looking for something like this:

```
select c.ProfileId, Count(*) from @tblCheck as a
inner join Profile_attribute as b on a.AttributeID = b.AttributeID and a.Value = b.Value
inner join Profile as c on c.ProfileID = b.ProfileID
Group by c.ProfileID
```